# python dataframe filtering combination of or and and

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I'm trying to filter a dataframe based on the following condition:

colA = alpha OR beta

colB = gamma

I've tried the following

```
filtered_df = (df[(df['colA'] == 'alpha') & (df['colB'] == 'gamma')]) | (df[(df['colA'] == 'beta') & (df['colB'] == 'gamma')])
```

But this doesn't work and I get the following error message :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'
```

What would be the most pythonic way to achieve the desired outcome?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that when you put `df[(df['colA'] == 'alpha') & (df['colB'] == 'gamma')]` that returns the `True` values for that statement. As the error say those are not bool values.

Comment: Here's a correction to your formula, although @AnuragDabas has the better solution.   `df[((df['colA'] == 'alpha') & (df['colB'] == 'gamma')) | ((df['colA'] == 'beta') & (df['colB'] == 'gamma'))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try `loc`+`isin()`+`eq()`:

```
filtered_df =df.loc[(df['colA'].isin(['alpha','beta'])) & (df['colB'].eq('gamma'))]
```

Now If you print `filtered_df` you will get your filtered dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
df.loc[((df['colA'] == 'alpha') | (df['colA'] == 'beta')) & (df['colB'] == 'gamma')]
```